# Non-interactive auto-refresh stale OAuth Token with Googlesheets package

Tags: launchd, r-googlesheets, non-interactive

I'm trying to automatically run an r script to download a private Google Sheet every hour. It always works fine when I'm interactively using R. It also works fine during the first hour after I automate the script with `launchd`.

It stops working an hour after I start automating it with `launchd`. I think the problem is that after one hour the access token changes, and the non-interactive version isn’t waiting for the auto refreshing of the OAuth token. Here is the error that I get from the error report:

> Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
>   Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
>   Calls: gs_auth ...  ->  -> cache_token -> saveRDS -> gzfile
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In gzfile(file, mode) :
>     cannot open compressed file '.httr-oauth', probable reason 'Permission denied'
>   Execution halted

I'm using Jenny Bryan's googlesheets package. Here is the code that I initially use to register the sheet, and then save the oAuth token:

```
gToken <- gs_auth() # Run this the first time to get the oAuth information
saveRDS(gToken, "/Users/…/gToken.rds") # Save the oAuth information for non-interactive use
```

I then use the following script in the file that I automate with `launchd`:

```
gs_auth(token = "/Users/…/gToken.rds")
```

How can I avoid this error when running the script automatically with `launchd`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about launchd but I had the same problem when I wanted to run a R script automatically from the Windows task planer. Changing the 'cache' attribute value to FALSE did the trick for me [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pprlC.png

You can find the solution here: https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/262

To authenticate once in the browser in order to get a token file, I did this:

```
token_file <- gs_auth(new_user = TRUE, cache = FALSE)
saveRDS(token_file, "googlesheets_token.rds")
```

Automatic login afterwards via:

```
gs_auth(token = paste0(path_scripts, "googlesheets_token.rds"), 
verbose = TRUE, cache = FALSE)
```